# What are these launch/debug configuration options that I didn't define, and why are they there / how can I get rid of them?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, flutter-debug

I'm using VS Code Studio for Flutter.
I cannot delete some devices in the Run and Debug section in VS Code Studio, the devices I marked in green in the picture.
There are devices that are not in my launch.json file, how do I clear these devices?

[Screenshot_VSCode_RunAndDebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2echQ.png)

My json file content;

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Android",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "deviceId": "emulator-5554",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug"
        },
        {
            "name": "Chrome",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "deviceId": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug"
        },
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "All Devices",
            "configurations": [
                "Android",
                "Chrome"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all of those are actually "Devices" in the Dart/Flutter sense of the word. More generically, these are [launch configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). The dropdown is for selecting launch configurations.

The one in your screenshot named `CMake: CMake Script` [is registered dynamically by the CMake Tools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/6876476d1ec34efdda25c1ce0cfcaf931b6bc5de/src/debug/debugConfigurationProvider.ts#L13). There related blog documentation about it [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/debug-vcpkg-portfiles-in-cmake-script-mode-with-visual-studio-code/#debugging-in-cmake-script-mode-without-a-configuration).

The other Flutter ones highlighted in your screenshot are also [dynamically generated- by the Dart extension](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/0f3afe552c2cd918b0031fc1b77ede100b3fbea8/src/extension/providers/debug_config_provider.ts#L872). If you're interested in how it's deciding what to provide dynamically, see https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/master/src/shared/vscode/device_manager.ts#L318

To generalize, if you want to figure out why a launch configuration is listed for selection without you defining it manually anywhere, then go read the source code of your extensions and find out where / how they use VS Code's [`DebugConfigurationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DebugConfigurationProvider) API. If they enable any mechanism for you to control it, great. If they don't, either accept it, or try to think of a feature request you'd like to make and raise an issue ticket in the extension's issue tracker requesting that feature.